# Why does an ajax form inside of an if statement submit twice if it is submitted after first failing the condition?

Tags: ajax, forms, ajax-forms

Consider the code below. If `myField1` does NOT equal `myField2`, then the alert appears. When I click okay on the alert pop up my form is still there, with all of the fields still populated with the data I had previously entered. However, when I modify the fields so that `myField1` DOES equal `myField2`, and then submit the form it is actually submitted TWICE! Why is this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var myField1 = $('#myID1).val();
    var myField2 = $('#myID2).val();
    if(myField1 == myField2)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'myFile.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {myData:myField1,
                   myData2:myField2},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('These two fields are not equal!)
    }
});
});
```

Comment: If you don't modify the values and submit again does the other alert appear twice?

Comment: no, it doesn't appear twice.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I found this on another question and it solves the problem:

```
$('#myForm').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function() {
    // do stuff here...
});
```

By unbinding the event, then re-binding it, the form no longer submits twice.

Answer (score -1):

Your submit event is going to fire the submit action of the form unless you prevent it from doing so. Running an AJAX call in does not prevent this from happening. You need to stop this yourself.

You need:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
...
```

Comment: -1 It is not enough to prevent the "submit" event. On second post a new bind() will occur. @Nancy Collier 's solution has been tested and works 100%.